# php version in apt - does it correspond to version on php.net and if not how to upgrade to latest release

Tags: upgrade, apt, apache2, php

So I'm setting up a lamp web server based on ubuntu 13.04 raring. I've installed all required software and run apt-get update and upgrade.

When I run php info it reports php version 5.4.9-4ubuntu or something similar. Does this correspond to the release 5.4.9 on the php.net site. If so what is the best way to update to the latest 5.4 or 5.5 minor release?

I previously tried installing from source but this only updated the command line version of php. Apache was still reporting the same release.

Comment: Thank you for the link and believe me I have not been shy of google in trying to work this out. Please can you clarify for me and possibly present ad an answer so I can accept. What you saying is they are not in fact the same version. At some point ubuntu decide to abandon updating the php version and instead start applying bug fixes themselves. So when I see version 5.4.9-4 ubuntu it is version 5.4.9 with a load of security/bug fixes which probably cover any important updates which were included in the later minor releases

Comment: I'm not sure I do need the latest release. I certainly need 5.4 as I'm running laravel and some of the packages I use are dependent on 5.4 features features I would also welcome the finally block coming in 5.5 but have survived so far without it

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu backports fixes. That is what the inclusion of the packages in the repository is for and why you receive updates on your system. :) A 1.2.3-ubuntu4 version may include fixes from 1.2.4 and 1.3.5 or whatever. You'll have to consult the changelog for what is actually in a x.x.x-ubuntuY version. It's just a freeze on features and API, so new features or API-breaking stuff won't make it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I think I'll be sticking with 5.4 till saucy salamander then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the latest releases then I would download them directly on launchpad, or adding the development ppa to my source list.

- [php on lauchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5)

Comment: Thanks for the link. +1 I'm leaving it open a minute to see if someone can confirm what I have written in the comments.